# Check if package is available?

Tags: node.js, npm

I'd like to know if `require(pkgName)` would succeed, that is, if the package with name `pkgName` is available. How do I best test for that?

I know I can do

```
try {
  require(pkgName)
} catch (err) {
  available = false
}
```

but this swallows load errors, and I'd also like to avoid `require`'ing the package if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way is to use [`require.resolve()`](http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_require_resolve), since it does not actually run any code contained in the module.

> Use the internal `require()` machinery to look up the location of a module, but rather than loading the module, just return the resolved filename.

Just like `require`, `resolve` throws if the module is not found, so it needs to be wrapped in `try`/`catch`.

Answer (score 1):

Don't think you can work around using `require`, but you can specifically check for `MODULE_NOT_FOUND` errors:

```
function moduleExists(mod) {
  try {
    require(mod);
  } catch(e) {
    if (e.code === 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND')
      return false;
    throw e;
  };
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm showing with the "swig" module. There might be better ways, but this works for me.

```
var swig; 
try { 
    swig = require('swig');
} catch (err) {
    console.log(" [FAIL]\t Cannot load swig.\n\t Have you tried installing it? npm install swig");
}
if (swig != undefined) {
    console.log(" [ OK ]\t Module: swig");
}
```